# Remove the wall which am not sure is load bearing wall

Tags: joists

I have removed a stair wall but not sure if it was a load bearing wall or not.

That’s a stair wall and the house is townhouse and on top floor the wall is not attached to the loft.

Added a picture and highlighted the joist which makes me concern with red.

Please advise to see if it’s load bearing wall and put a column under the block.

Also i have added 2*(2*4) timber under the joist above the wall.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's going to be tough giving you an accurate opinion remotely; you should probably consult a local expert. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: "Measure twice, cut once" applies here.  Too late now, but it's really important to make load-bearing determinations **before** removing supports.

Answer (score 1):

> I have removed a stair wall but not sure if it was a load bearing wall or not.

This may sound like a trivial answer, but - you should **just check**.

#### With the authorities

In many (most?) states in the world, house construction plans must be submitted to a local/regional planning body where they are kept in an archive. go get a copy. The plans should somehow (fingers crossed) indicate which walls bear load.

It's probably a good idea to have a copy of those plans anyway.

#### Consult a professional

Find a home constructor - or a company which does home construction - and ask them to determine that for you. They will probably take a bit of money, but not that much.

Show them the plans if you have them!

Newbie sentiment: Better to feel sorry for wasting a bit of money than to feel sorry for cracks or a collapse of part of your house.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that joist is there because it is the edge of the first floor ceiling in front of the stairs (I encountered something similar when raising the ceiling over my first floor landing where I kept hitting my head - above it was a pitifully small closet which is now a storage nook. In my case, there was no wall or support post there). It probably extends to the wall containing the door we see in the picture.

The wall would not have been load bearing for the rest of the joists, because they run in the same direction as it, but may have been load bearing for that joist, and by extension, all the joists that were cut to accommodate it. Placing a supporting 4*4 post there, as you say you did, seems a reasonable choice. Also gives you something to attach the now necessary handrail to.

But I'm no building engineer - you might want a specialist's opinion before you finish.